# How to parse/leach/extract a ASP.net website Content using Ruby or PHP or Java?

Tags: java, php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing

I am  doing a hobby project to scrape the content of an ASP.net website using Ruby  or PHP or Java . For example if the  website  url " www.myaspnet.com/home.aspx" . i would like to  extract the unicode text content from home.aspx and paste it to a notepad . Is there any libraries available in any of the above mentioned languages ? . Can anybody help me regarding this by providing suitable resources .

Thanks!

Comment: I do believe the word for this is *scrape*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to scrape content.

You don't "paste it in notepad", you just write it to a simple text file (which you could then open in notepad, or any other program that can read a text file).

Generally:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://example.com/url.asp');
//do some stuff to extract what you want and format it.  Probably using simplexml, or regular expressions to do the extraction
$fp = fopen('some_file.txt');
fwrite($fp,$stuff);
fclose($fp);
```

And you're done.

Comment: As a sidenote, if you DO choose to use a regular expression, make sure to make it flexible, ie, use `"\s+"` instead of a bunch of spaces. It's very easy for people to intentionally, or even unintentionally screw up a rigid regular expression.

Comment: Indeed, regex are dirty, and you'll get sick and have to go to a doctor and take care of it.  Infintely better to parse the output properly.

Comment: @tim Thanks for your answer, i tried your script but i am getting the html content of the page , which can also be done by using a curl , But my requirement i wanted to scrape only the unicode text content , Only text not along with the html tags.

Comment: Right, once you get the html content, you'll need to extract and process the stuff you want.  As others have pointed out, you can do this in a variety of ways using simplexml, dom, or xpath.

If your needs are very simple, you could probably just pass the entire HTML contents into strip_tag() and take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP you should be able to do without too much difficulties, you can use [curl](http://jp.php.net/curl) for getting the content and [simplexml](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) & [dom](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to navigate into html.

You might also want to take a look at [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp) for extracting content easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you need some kind of screen scraping and you favor Ruby,then you can check [scRubyt](http://scrubyt.org/) or watch [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/173-screen-scraping-with-scrapi) screen cast by Ryan Bates.

Answer (score 0):

With Java you could write a simple utility using [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/) to extract the text from a page, then follow each of the links presented on the page - visiting those recursively and performing the same task.

It should be a fairly trivial exercise, external links need to be treated with some caution though, depending on how far you want to go with indexing.

Answer (score 0):

This [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/173-screen-scraping-with-scrapi) basically shows how to scrap a website step by step in Ruby. It uses it the output a rails application, it should be easy to focus on just the Ruby library ( **ScrAPI** ).